# ViewPager runs slower on the same device while changing minimum SDK version

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, android-manifest

I've noticed a strange behavior of a viewpager when launching it on a device running Android 4.1.

When I declare minSdkVersion 15 or 16 in the app manifest file the viewpager paging transitions run smooth and clear but when I change the minSdkVersion to 10 the paging transitions become slow and choppy.

How come the minSdkVersion causing this strange behavior on the same device. From the android documentation the minimum SDK versions should only prevent the user from installing the app if its device level is lower than the versions mentioned but it should not downgrade the performance of the app in any way:

> minSdkVersion - An integer designating the minimum API Level required
>   for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user
>   from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower
>   than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare
>   this attribute.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Android turns on hardware-acceleration by default if you target a specific SDK-Version (> 4.0 I think). That is probably what causes the difference.

Comment: I will accept it as an answer: The problem was that there was no target parameter at all and thus android took the min SDK version as a target version. Because of that hardware acceleration was not activated. Thanks.